# oAuth 1.0 REST API with Magento 1.9, how to get oauth_signature like postman does?

Tags: php, magento, oauth, postman

I'm trying to access a Magento 1.9 REST API in php, which only supports authentication in oAuth 1.0.

Now, I have it working in Postman, but it's doing some sort of magic to do oAuth that it isn't disclosing. It even has a button for the code from the request, but the nonce, time and signature must change with every request.

I'm making a GET request to example.com/api/rest/products (production site, url changed for privacy) with the consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access secret. It returns a proper response with all the products. Here's the curl code it outputs...

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.example.com/api/rest/products",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"some_key\",oauth_token=\"some_token\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1529691153\",oauth_nonce=\"0fVylxHPUqv\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"LTJHEp2A5mczD3xrYxbWW2BHlQk%3D\"",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: d684d11c-498e-4760-8709-76777e8ea75d"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

This doesn't work, fails every time due to the nonce already being used. If I change the nonce it says the signature is invalid.

Here's the code Magento's ancient docs recommend, which fails with 403 Not Authorized.

```
$baseUrl = 'https://www.example.com';
$callbackUrl = 'http://otherexample.test/test';
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = $baseUrl."/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = $baseUrl.'/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = $baseUrl.'/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = $baseUrl.'/api/rest';

$consumerKey = 'some_key';
$consumerSecret = 'some_secret';

session_start();

if(! isset($_SESSION['state'])) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = null;
}

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}

try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new \OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

        $resourceUrl = $apiUrl . "/products";

        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }

} catch (\OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "&lt;br/&gt;";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

Basically, I think I need to somehow generate the nonce and signature like postman is. I'm giving postman my access token and secret, but thats of course not in the response because a secret never should be. So how is it doing it? Every time I run a request in postman it succeeds and the code sample has different data in it. Every time I run it in php it fails with not authorized.

I'd prefer to use something more object oriented like Guzzle than curl, but I'll take whatever I can get at this point to get this external site to be able to use Magento 1.x REST API.

[image: Here is what is working in postman, with the keys removed.]

Answer (score 1):

yes, you have to generate a random nonce for every request sent.

```
let nonceObj = Math.random()
  .toString(36)
  .replace(/[^a-z]/, "")
  .substr(2);
```

This is how i did in JS.

Comment: @CertainPerformance How can i get my oAuth 2 details, i have my all oAuth 1 details,  how can i get my oAuth 2 details?

Comment: @Rathinam I have absolutely no idea.